# insert form values with database lookup without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

I have a form with 5 fields. 
Name
Last Name
Date of Birth
Occupation 
Place of Birth

When user fills name and last name, I want the rest of the form to be filled from database without refreshing the page or user doing anything.

I am using php and jquery.

Here is my html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
<input type="text" name="occupation" id="occupation">
<input type="text" name="date_of_birth" id="date_of_birth">
<input type="text" name="place_of_birth" id="place_of_birth">
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#lastname').blur(function () 
    {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var lastname = $("#lastname").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "get.php",
        type: "POST", 
        data: "name="+name+"&lastname="+lastname,
        success: function(data)
        {
            if (data == "Error")
            {
                alert("error-1"+data);
            }
            else
            {
                var fields = data.split(",");
                if (fields.length < 3) 
                {
                    alert("error-2"+data);  
                }
                else
                {

                    $("#occupation").val(fields[0]);
                    $("#date_of_birth").val(fields[1]);
                    $("#place_of_birth").val(fields[2]);

                }
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) 
        {
               alert("error-3"+data);    
        }   
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the php page:

```
<?php
$name= $_REQUEST['name'];
$lastname= $_REQUEST['lastname'];
if($name == "mike" && $lastname = "brown")
{
    echo  "cook,1980-10-10,NYC";
}

?>
```

It works now.

Comment: Read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-- Edit #1**
Maybe this example can help you to understand how to use it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "phppage.php",
    type: "POST", // Or get as you like
    data: "name="+name+"&lastname="+lastname,
    success: function(data)
    {
        // As i said, here in "data" you have what the server returned
        // You can return the last field delimited with a , and do something like:
        if (data == "Error")
        {
            // If something went wrong in your Database or invalid "name" or "last name"
            // You can return "Error" in the PHP page so the Javascript know something is wrong
            // and handle this error
        }
        else
        {
            var fields = data.split(",");
            if (fields.length < 3) {
                // As above.
                // Something went wrong or invalid response
            }
            else
            {
                // In fields array you have what server said.
                            // Here you can reload the page, change page do what you want
            }
        }

    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) 
    {
        // Error here
    }   
});
```

It pass name and lastname to the server and wait for a response like:
field1,field2,field3

The PHP page should be something like..

```
<?php

// Connect to the server
// Send query to the server

if ($isEverythingOK) {
    echo $field1 . "," . $field2 . "," . $field3;
}
else {
    echo "Error";
}

?>
```

[Ajax](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) - [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) + PHP page

A php page where you pass the 5 fields, add it in the database and return something like "OK" if everything is OK or an error if something went wrong.

Example

```
$.ajax({
    url : "URL to PHP page",
    success : function (data) {
          if (data === "OK") { /* all ok, here you can update the page to show the new field */ alert("OK"); }
          else { /* Error */ alert("Error"); }
    },
    error : function (xhr, status, error) {
        // Request error
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Comment: I need to only pass name and last name fields to php page and get the rest of the field's values from database.

Comment: i have added an example which could help you

Comment: It works now, thank you! I have posted the working code above. For some reason, special chars won't pass the if statements at get.php